# Efficiently Checking for matching values in an Array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this one :

```
$pref_array = ('android/cbnj','android/fgngh','android/vfjnf','apple/jns','apple/dvjnvd','pictues/djnf','pictures/djnf','pictures/hjf','pictures/cvjbv');
```

Number of elements that have `android/` in them can be anywhere between 0 to N, where N is size of array. Now, I have to find if a value like 'android/`or 'buffalo/` etc. exists in any of these elements. If it exists I do some stuff otherwise I check for other values. Here is my code :

```
$cCount = count($pref_array);
for($j=1;$j<$cCount;$j++) {
  $code = $pref_array[$j];
  if(strpos($code, 'android/') !== false) { 
    // Do Android Related Stuff just once.
    $j = $cCount;  
  } 
}
for($j=1;$j<$cCount;$j++) {
  $code = $pref_array[$j];
  if(strpos($code, 'buffalo/') !== false) { 
    // Do Buffalo Related Stuff just once.
    $j = $cCount;  
  } 
}
for($j=1;$j<$cCount;$j++) {
  $code = $pref_array[$j];
  if(strpos($code, 'apple/') !== false) { 
    // Do Apple Related Stuff just once.
    $j = $cCount;  
  } 
}
```

and so on. It works but I don't find it efficient enough. Each time I am iterating through the array from the beginning. Is there any way I can iterate through the array just once?

I am setting `$j = $cCount` to break out of loop.

Comment: you can use an `AND|OR` operator to combine all three, if that's what the question is about

Comment: It's not really clear. By the way, on your code, you are doing stuff with all `prefixes` right ? Why you are not using a if else in your loop?

Comment: you can use switch case

Comment: Also something is weird... Why do you set `$j = $cCount;` on each loop ... ??

Comment: @zeflex, @Fred I have do do stuff just once for each case, so I am breaking out of loop by setting `$j = $cCount`.

Comment: what I meant was this `if((strpos($code, 'android/') !== false) AND|OR (strpos($code, 'buffalo/') !== false)) {...}` etc. using either `AND` or `OR` or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think you misunderstood the question. someOne has provided an answer that I think should work.

Comment: well then jump on it and test it

Comment: @SujataHulsurkar to break a loop, simply use `break;` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: If you have several android, do you want to do stuff on all android then others or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @zeflex I want to do stuff just once if android exists no matter how many times it occurs. The accepted answer works perfectly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$android_stuff_done = $buffalo_stuff_done = $apple_stuff_done = false;
foreach($pref_array as $value) {
    if(!$android_stuff_done && strpos($value, 'android/') !== false) {
         // Do android stuff once!
    }
    if(!$buffalo_stuff_done && strpos($value, 'buffalo/') !== false) {
        // Do buffalo stuff once!
    }
    if(!$apple_stuff_done && strpos($value, 'apple/') !== false) {
        // Do apple stuff once!
    }
}
```